# Using curl information with scrapy shell

Tags: python, curl, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to get some information of some websites. To be more precise, I'm using it from the scrapy shell, with this command:

```
scrapy shell 'https://foo.bar'
```

But it seems https://foo.bar doesn't allow information to be shown if it's made from scrapy shell. I noticed the same happened when I tried to get that data with `curl https://foo.bar` (even adding user agent information). So I looked on Firefox and I could get that data with the curl command generated by this:

[image]

The scrapy docs recommend using something called "curl2scrapy" to "convert" that curl command parameters into something that would work with scrapy. The matter is I don't know how to make them work with scrapy shell. Thank you in advance.

PD: I can't use webdrivers such as splash or selenium.

Comment: You can issue a complex request from the shell after you have started it. Check the shell documentation.

Comment: Hi! is your question still actual?